# Scale WPF DrawingGroup to fit in the current Element

Tags: c#, wpf, vector-graphics

I have loaded a set of vector data into my application whose bounds extend from `{-165835.328125, 6582072.5}` to `{-64674.02734375, 6609767}` giving a Width of 101161.30078125 and a Height of 27694.5.

I want to show this data on my `FrameworkElement` which defaults to 663 pixels wide and 468 pixels high and obviously resize it when the element is resized. As far as I could judge in order scale my `DrawingGroup` I need to create a `ScaleTransform` and add it to a `TransformGroup` which I can then set as the `Transform` of the `DrawingGroup` - I figure I also need an offset in order to bring the origin location of my data to the top left corner of the view, although in retrospect I might be better off aligning the centres.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
var transformWidth = this.drawingGroup.Bounds.Width;

var scale = width / transformWidth;
var left = this.drawingGroup.Bounds.Left * -1;
var top = this.drawingGroup.Bounds.Top * -1;

var translateTransform = new TranslateTransform(left, top);
var scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
scaleTransform.CenterX = (drawingGroup.Bounds.Width / 2);
scaleTransform.CenterY = (drawingGroup.Bounds.Height / 2);
scaleTransform.ScaleX = scale;
scaleTransform.ScaleY = scale;

var tg = new TransformGroup()
{
    Children = new TransformCollection() { translateTransform, scaleTransform }
};

var oldTransform = this.drawingGroup.Transform;
this.drawingGroup.Transform = tg;
context.DrawDrawing(this.drawingGroup);
this.drawingGroup.Transform = oldTransform;
```

This is rough on multiple levels but the main one bothering me right now is that it doesn't work. I can adjust the data on input ( as in if I translate the points manually when generating the geometry ) and it will draw only slightly wrong so I think the geometry exists but is outside the visible area, as far as I can tell the translation just isn't doing anything. I tried pushing the transforms onto the `DrawingContext` too but that didn't seem to work either ( I would quite like to be able to maintain the original coordinates on the `DrawingGroup` so I can relate things back to them later, hence the possibly unnecessary Transform switcheroo ) and when I inspect the child collection of the DrawingGroup their geometry seems untranslated after the translate was applied- I don't know whether or not that is correct.

What do I need to do to get my data visible in my `FrameworkElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bounds property takes the current transform into account.

Reset the Transform property before accessing the Bounds:

```
drawingGroup.Transform = Transform.Identity;

var bounds = drawingGroup.Bounds;
var scale = width / bounds.Width;
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Translate(-bounds.X, -bounds.Y);
matrix.Scale(scale, scale);

drawingGroup.Transform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
```

---

As a note, in order to keep the thickness of the Drawings' Pens, better transform the underlying Geometries instead of the Drawings.

Comment: This is a good answer, I am not sure if it was specific to the pens but transforming the geometries rather than the group enabled it to draw correctly- I suspect the pens might have been reduce to invisibly small.